# How to convert an integer into ByteIterator in Java for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, hashmap, ycsb

I am using YCSB for benchmarking. I am writing a custom code in Java. I have two fields which are of String and Int type but the db.insert method takes a `HashMap` of `<String,ByteIterator>` type. How can I convert String and integer into `ByteIterator` type? Please help

Comment: Can we see you code at least? :)

Comment: create hashmap with key = your int and value = your string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
new com.yahoo.ycsb.StringByteIterator(string);
```

I suggest you look at the `MongoDbClient` to see how it is supported already.